# how do you create a custom table looks like this

Tags: c#, winforms

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi9Iz.jpg

i am trying to create a table in c# which should look like at example above and it should be usable in a loop. example: i have two variables called "text" and "author" big box belongs to text and right bottom box belongs to author. those variables available in a loop. what i want to is fill those boxes and make it compatible with loop. i managed to solve this with textboxes but i couldn't figure out how to make them stay under another one.

Comment: your question is not clear. what type of table is it , html, image, WPF app or win forms.

Comment: What component you want to use? an datagridview an tableLayoutPanel? or whatever component it is you just want something that appears like that?

Comment: it doesnt matter as long i accomplish what i want, can i make use of tablelayoutpanel in a loop? i want it to created for each text and author data

Comment: use a repeater control or winforms equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way (that i am aware of) to do what you want is with an usercontrols and a flowLayoutPanel so we do it as follow

### Create an UserControl

create it with panels or textBox in the way you want your table to be, i did like so
[image: Table likeUserControl]

### Create a flowLayoutPanel

put it where you like it to be and set those properties

```
this.flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
this.flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
this.flowLayoutPanel1.WrapContents = false;
```

add as much table like UserControl you want in it the result should be as follow
[image: Result]

Comment: thank you it worked, how do i set textbox height equal to number of lines? i mean i set textbox height to static value but it looks ugly

Comment: Sorry I searched here I did not found a way to set it easily you could open a question on how to make a textBox change its height when the number of lines change